# Selecting and plotting months in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have a time series dataset in this format with two columns  date (e.g Jan 1980, Feb 1980...Dec 2013) and it's corresponding temperature.  This dataset is from 1980 to 2013. I am trying to subset and plot time series in ggplot for the months separately (e.g I only want all Feb so that I can plot it using ggplot). Tried the following, but the Feb1 is empty

```
Feb1 <- subset(temp, date ==5)
```

The structure of my dataset is:

```
'data.frame':   408 obs. of  2 variables:
$ date   :Class 'yearmon'  num [1:359] 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 ...
$ temp: int  16.9 12.7 13 6 6.0 5 6 10.9 0.9 16 ...
```

Comment: Was any of the answers of any use to you?

Comment: Yes  thank you all very much. For showing me different ways of doing the same thing! Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?:

```
library(zoo)

# Generating some data:
df <- data.frame(date = as.yearmon("1980-01") + 0:407/12, val = rnorm(408))

# Subsetting to get a specific month:
df.sub <- subset(df, format(df$date,"%b")=="Jan")

# The actual plot:
ggplot(df.sub) + geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(date), y = val))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your column being in a 'yearmon' class comes in the format "mm YY". I'm a little confused by how you are subsetting the data by 'date==5'. Below I try a method.

```
temp$month<-substr(temp$date,1,3)
Feb1<-subset(temp,month=='Feb')

#more elegant

Feb1<-subset(temp,substr(temp$date,1,3)=='Feb')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly plot the subset in ggplot2 without creating a new data frame.

Based on RStudent's solution:

```
library(zoo)

# Generating some data:
df <- data.frame(date = as.yearmon("1980-01") + 0:407/12, val = rnorm(408))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df[format(df$date,"%b")=="Jan", ], aes(x = as.Date(date), y = val))+
   geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data to zoo, use `cycle` to split into months and `autoplot.zoo` to plot.  Below we show four different ways to plot.  First we plot just January.  Then we plot all the months with each month in a separate panel and then we plot all months with each month as a separate series all in the same panel.  Finally we use `monthplot` (not ggplot2) to plot them all in a single panel in a different manner.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

# test data
set.seed(123)
temp <- data.frame(date = as.yearmon(1980 + 0:479/12), value = rnorm(480))

z <- read.zoo(temp, FUN = identity) # convert to zoo

# split into 12 series and cbind them together so zz480 is 480 x 12
# Then aggregate to zz which is 40 x 12

zz480 <- do.call(cbind, split(z, cycle(z)))
zz <- aggregate(zz480, as.numeric(trunc(time(zz480))), na.omit)

### now we plot this 4 different ways
#####################################

# 1. plot just January
autoplot(zz[, 1]) + ggtitle("Jan")

# 2. plot each in separate panel
autoplot(zz)

# 3. plot them all in a single panel
autoplot(zz, facet = NULL)

# 4. plot them all in a single panel in a different way (not using ggplot2)
monthplot(z)
```

Note that an alternative way to calculate `zz` would be:

```
zz <- zoo(matrix(coredata(z), 40, 12, byrow=TRUE), unique(as.numeric(trunc(time(z)))))
```

**Update:** Added plot types and improved the approach.